# Can we ask user for credit card number or paypal details,store credit card number on our server, can we use SSL in iphone application for transaction?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ssl, transactions, credit-card

Can we get credit card number from user or Paypal details & use them for premium service of our application ?

Does apple accept this application if we directly get this information & use it in our api on server for transaction? Will using SSL be accepted by apple ?

I have checked from 
1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763306/credit-card-purchase-of-physical-goods-via-an-iphone-application

2) [Receiving payments trough PayPal and Credit Card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707701/receiving-payments-trough-paypal-and-credit-card)

3) [Using the PayPal API in an iPhone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366864/using-the-paypal-api-in-an-iphone-application)

but not clear about all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal will not give you your customer's credit card information. The customer might not even have paid with a credit card -- they could have used PayPal balance, eCheck, etc.

You can use PayPal IPN to get information about a transaction.

Comment: They will not give you any credit card information, including the number or expiration date.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand it isn't 100% clear.
If you'll sell music or additional levels, or some additional item in the game - Apple will reject it. Because for this cases there is In-App purchase.

If you sell something like flight tickets - it won't be a problem. AFAIK paypla provides an API, and there are few APIs wich allows you to process Credit Crads without Paypal.

Comment: So what would be good for me for my application that instantly requires credit card or paypal information for transaction.

Comment: Making it a website / webapp rather than an iPhone application would seem to be a better solution in this case.