# PayPal Payment Provider in C#

Tags: c#, paypal

I was wondering if PayPal has a payment service which allows the users to enter their credit card details on my site (the user wouldn't even be aware they are paying by paypal).  I then need to make sure it handles repeat payments and refunds.  Basically i need to create a paypal service which implements the following:

```
public interface IPaymentService {
    Response ValidateCard(NetworkCredential credential, int transactionID, decimal amount, string ipAddress, CardDetails cardDetails, Address billingAddress, Options options);
    Response RepeatCard(NetworkCredential credential, int oldTransactionID, int newTransactionID, decimal amount);
    Response RefundCard(NetworkCredential credential, int refundedTransactionID, int newTransactionID, decimal amount);
}

public class Address {
    public virtual string Address1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Address2 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Address3 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Town { get; set; }
    public virtual string County { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
    public virtual string Postcode { get; set; }
}

public class CardDetails {
    public string CardHolderName { get; set; }
    public CardType CardType { get; set; }
    public string CardNumber { get; set; }
    public int ExpiryDateMonth { get; set; }
    public int ExpiryDateYear { get; set; }
    public string IssueNumber { get; set; }
    public string Cv2 { get; set; }
}

public class Response {
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class Options {
    public bool TestStatus { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
}
```

Usually this is quite trivual with other other payment providers eg PayPoint (soap service) and SagePay.

Reading the paypal documentation is giving me a headache so i thought i'd ask here.  Really appreciate the help.  Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Receiving payments trough PayPal and Credit Card](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707701/receiving-payments-trough-paypal-and-credit-card)

Comment: @George Stocker - That's not a duplicate.  The question you linked to is PHP and this question is C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they do.  Check out this documentation.

The direct payment api allows you to enter the card holder's info and then process it through the paypal system.

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_dcc_hub-outside

```
//process payment
            Paypal toPayment = new Paypal();
            toPayment.BillingAddress = new Address(txt_BillingAddr1.Text, txt_BillingAddr2.Text, txt_BillingCity.Text, ddl_BillingState.SelectedValue, txt_BillingZip.Text, "");
            toPayment.BillingCountry = com.paypal.soap.api.CountryCodeType.US;
            toPayment.BillingFName = txt_BillingFName.Text;
            toPayment.BillingLName = txt_BillingLName.Text;
            toPayment.BillingMName = txt_BillingMName.Text;
            toPayment.BillingPhoneNumber = txt_BillingPhone.Text;
            toPayment.BillingSuffix = txt_BillingSuffix.Text;
            toPayment.ContactPhoneNumber = txtPhone.Text;
            toPayment.CreditCardExpireMonth = Convert.ToInt32(ddl_CCExpireMonth.SelectedIndex + 1);
            toPayment.CreditCardExpireYear = Convert.ToInt32(ddl_CCExpireYear.SelectedValue);
            toPayment.CreditCardNumber = txt_CreditCard.Text;
            toPayment.CreditCardSecurityCode = txt_CCID.Text;
            switch (lst_CCTypes.SelectedValue)
            {
                case "Visa":
                    toPayment.CreditCardType = com.paypal.soap.api.CreditCardTypeType.Visa;
                    break;
                case "MasterCard":
                    toPayment.CreditCardType = com.paypal.soap.api.CreditCardTypeType.MasterCard;
                    break;
                case "AmericanExpress":
                    toPayment.CreditCardType = com.paypal.soap.api.CreditCardTypeType.Amex;
                    break;
                case "Discover":
                    toPayment.CreditCardType = com.paypal.soap.api.CreditCardTypeType.Discover;
                    break;
            }
            toPayment.UserHostAddress = Request.UserHostAddress;
            toPayment.OrderTotal = StaticMethods.getDecimal(lbl_TotalPrice_cout.Text, 0);

            //set API Profile
            toPayment.APIProfile = Master.PayPal_API_Profile;

            DoDirectPaymentResponseType toResponse = new DoDirectPaymentResponseType();
            toResponse = toPayment.processDirectPaymentTransaction();
```

Here is a little bit more for you... this is actual code from an actual production site that i work on that takes payments via paypal

toResponse contains an Ack property.... so you can do something like

```
switch(toResponse.Ack)
{
case AckCodeType.Failure;
     // The card is bad. void transaction.
     lblResponse = toResponse.Errors[0].LongMessage;
     Break;
case AckCodeType.Success
     // The card is good.  Go forward with process
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, PayPal offers this under [Website Payments Pro](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_WPWebsitePaymentsPro#id0d434473-8817-4a4e-822a-bb23730a17e7). You can read more about it [here](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_WPWebsitePaymentsPro#id0d434473-8817-4a4e-822a-bb23730a17e7).

[image]

The first flow is of Direct Payment and second is Express Checkout. Customer enters card details on your website under Direct Payment.